# Joining tables in Zend Framework throwing application error

Tags: php, zend-framework, join

I have this problem after upgrading Zend Framework library to 1.12. It was working fine with version 1.11.

The problem is when I joined two tables, I got this error:

> Application error
>
> **Exception information:**
>
> Message: The specified Table does not have the same columns as the Row

This error is generated from Zend/Db/Table/Row/Abstract.php (**line 356**)

**My Table Structure**

```
Members:
  id (int)
  name (varchar)
  age (int)
  family_id (varchar)

Family:
  id (int)
  family_type (varchar)
```

**My Model:**

```
class Model_Member extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    public function getAll($params = array())
    {
        $select = $this->select();
        $select->setIntegrityCheck(false);

        $select->from("members", array('name', 'family_id'));
        $select->join('family', 'family.id = members.family_id', array('family_type'));

        $paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($select);
        $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(20);
        $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber(1);
        $paginator->setPageRange(10);

        return $paginator;
    }
}
```

**And then in my view file**

```
foreach($this->paginator as $row)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Your MODEL:

```
    class Model_Member extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
    {
    public function getAll($params = array(), $paged = 1)
   {
    $select = $this->select();
    $select->setIntegrityCheck(false);

    $select->from("members", array('name', 'family_id'));
    $select->join('family', 'family.id = members.family_id', array('family_type'));

    $adapter = new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbTableSelect($select);
    $paginator = new Zend_Paginator($adapter);
    $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(5)
              ->setCurrentPageNumber((int) $paged);

    return $paginator;
    }
 }
```

And view:

```
<?php if($this->data instanceof Zend_Paginator): ?>
                               <?php echo $this->paginationControl($this->data,
                                                                     'Sliding',
                                                                            'pathToController/_paginator.phtml', array('params'=>$params);?>// if you want pass some params.
```

Should work on you App, is working on my.

Comment: It's still not working. I am still getting the same error.

Have you tried joining two tables and then select few columns from the joined tables using zend framework v1.12? Do you mean to say that this works for you with v1.12